# Finding a max value in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am doing a problem where I need to use data from a csv file to find which film has the high gross total for each year.

I already have the dict 'year' with each film and the year it came out and the same for 'gross'.
Despite this, my code is still returning 0 as the max gross. What am I missing here?

```
def MaxGrossFinder(c):

    for film in year:
        MaxGross = 0                        
        f = int(gross[film])                        
        if year[film] == c:
            if f > MaxGross:
                MaxGross = f
    return MaxGross
```

Comment: I think it maybe because year[film] never equals c.

Comment: This is a rather awkward structure.

Comment: Why aren't you using [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max)?

Comment: `gross` is a global variable?

Comment: With what is filled year and gross

Comment: Not having access to your greater data structure, I can't say with complete certainty, but I will wager your issue is this line: `year[film] == c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `MaxGross` out of the `for-loop`:

```
def MaxGrossFinder(c):
    MaxGross = 0  
    for film in year:                      
        f = int(gross[film])                        
        if year[film] == c:
            if f > MaxGross:
                MaxGross = f
    return MaxGross
```

With `MaxGross = 0` inside the for-loop, all the prior iterations mean nothing. Only the last would affect `MaxGross`. That's probably not the intention.

Another problem might occur if `c` and `year[film]` are floats. Don't compare floats for equality (unless you know what you are doing) since floats can have inexact representations. Instead
define some concept of nearness:

```
def near(a,b,rtol=1e-5,atol=1e-8):        
   return abs(a-b)<(atol+rtol*abs(b))
```

and compare `if near(year[film],c)`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) function. It does this operation correctly.

```
max(int(gross[film]) for film in year if year[film] == c)
```

Your problem is that you set `MaxGross` to zero in each iteration. So all values but the last are ignored.

Please also look into creating a Film class and using one dict of film objects, rather than having multiple parallel dicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use max() directly,

```
    for film in year:
        if year[film]==c:
            print(max(int(gross[film]))
```